# With gradle in Android Studio, how to specify a productFlavors name for the "run" progress?

Tags: android, gradle

Here is a part of my build.gradle file. There are 2 productFlavors name:adult and weightloss

```
productFlavors {
    adult {
        packageName "com.xxx.yymadult"
    }
    weightloss {
        packageName "com.xxx.yymweightloss"
    }
}
```

When I press the "run" button to run the programme, It's always the "assembleAdultDebug" which is going to run.
The thing is, now I gotta test the "weightloss" product flavor, but I can't find a way to specify that flavor to be the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ and Android Studio provide a "Build Variants" selector UI. On my IntelliJ version, this UI can be found on the lower left side. On Mac, you can hit Command-Shift-A, and start typing "build variant" to find a direct link to it.

You should then see a drop-down menu that allows you to select the build flavour you want to run.